Best practices for combining dual mono to stereo?
I have two old-style telephone pickup coils, each of which has a 3.5mm mono (TS) male output. I made a simple adapter that just runs together the grounds from both inputs and connects each positive to a stereo channel on the TRS output jack, and it seems to work fine, but I wanted to ask if this was the best/proper way of doing this before I make a more permanent and well-built version. I'm running them directly into the microphone input of a small audio recorder, for context. I've tried searching around to find more info about this but can't seem to find anything amongst all the results for stereo to mono and other more common issues with similar search terms.

What you have done is exactly what the whole stereo thing is all about - having two spatially separated mics, each driving its own signal channel and, ultimately, its own human ear.
Variations over this are numerous, but this is the basic idea.
If the mono/stereo question is your only concern, go for it.
